# @Transactional Method to override data before new insert happens

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, transactions

I'm trying to delete all existing records in the postgres database, if we try to load a new dataset that contains data for the same date. I'm trying to use `@Transactional` with propagation, but the initial transaction needs to finish, before the NESTED, or REQUIRES_NEW Transaction comes in. So essentially the Transaction tries to insert into the database before the data was deleted, causing a unique constraint violation. Any help on understanding the flow of @Transactional would be very beneficial here. As I want to delete the data before I even attempt to insert the new data, as you can see by the `saveAllPositionData()` method. I need the `overwriteBpsData()` to commit its transaction before the insert statements are called in the original `saveAllPositionData()` method. Any thoughts on the flaw in my logic would be very helpful.

Thanks

```
  @Transactional
  public void saveAllBpsPositionData(InputStream is) throws IOException {

    log.info("Parsing position data...");
    BPSParsingResult bpsParsingResult = bpsPositionParser.parse(is);
    if (!bpsParsingResult.getBpsPositions().isEmpty()) {
      LocalDate businessDate = bpsParsingResult.getBpsPositions().get(0).getBusinessDate();
      overwriteBpsData(businessDate);
    }
    log.info("Saving BPS Position Data...");
    if (!bpsParsingResult.getBpsPositions().isEmpty()) {
      insertBpsPositionData(bpsParsingResult.getBpsPositions());
    }
    log.info("Saving BPS Price Data...");
    if (!bpsParsingResult.getBpsPrices().isEmpty()) {
      insertBpsPriceData(bpsParsingResult.getBpsPrices());
    }
  }

  private void insertBpsPositionData(List<BPSPositionTable> bpsPositions) {
    try (Connection connection = hikariDataSource.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement positionStatement = connection.prepareStatement(POSITION_SQL);
        PreparedStatement memoStatement = connection.prepareStatement(MEMO_SQL)) {
      int count = 0;
      for (BPSPositionTable position : bpsPositions) {
        positionStatement.clearParameters();
        positionStatement.setString(1, position.getSRMASKey());
        // ....
        // ....
        positionStatement.setInt(33, position.getWhenIssueIndicator());
        positionStatement.setDate(
            34,
            position.getBusinessDate() == null ? null : Date.valueOf(position.getBusinessDate()));
        positionStatement.addBatch();

        if ((count + 1) % batchSize == 0 || (count + 1) == bpsPositions.size()) {
          positionStatement.executeBatch();
          positionStatement.clearBatch();
          memoStatement.executeBatch();
          memoStatement.clearBatch();
        }

        if (position.getNumberOfMemos() > 0) {
          for (BPSMemoTable memoTable : position.getCorrespondingMemos()) {
            memoStatement.setString(1, memoTable.getSRMASKey());
            memoStatement.setString(2, memoTable.getMemoTypeIndicator());
            memoStatement.setBigDecimal(3, memoTable.getMemoTypeQuantity());
            memoStatement.setDate(
                4,
                memoTable.getBusinessDate() == null
                    ? null
                    : Date.valueOf(memoTable.getBusinessDate()));
            memoStatement.addBatch();
          }
        }
        count++;
      }
      log.info("BPS Position Data Saved Successfully!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.warn("Failure Inserting BPS Position Data: {}", e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  private void insertBpsPriceData(List<BPSPriceTable> bpsPrices) {
    try (Connection connection = hikariDataSource.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(PRICE_SQL)) {
      int count = 0;
      for (BPSPriceTable price : bpsPrices) {
        statement.setInt(1, price.getClientNumber());
        statement.setString(2, price.getCusip());
        statement.setString(3, price.getSymbol());
        statement.setString(4, price.getCurrency());
        // ...
        // ...
        statement.setString(15, price.getSedol());
        statement.setDate(
            16, price.getBusinessDate() == null ? null : Date.valueOf(price.getBusinessDate()));
        statement.addBatch();
        if ((count + 1) % batchSize == 0 || (count + 1) == bpsPrices.size()) {
          statement.executeBatch();
          statement.clearBatch();
        }
        count++;
      }
      log.info("BPS Price Data Saved Successfully!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.warn("Failure Inserting BPS Price Data: {}", e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) // Also have tried NESTED
  public void overwriteBpsData(LocalDate businessDate) {
    if (bpsMemoRepo.countByBusinessDate(businessDate) > 0) {
      log.warn(
              "BPS Memo record(s) found by {} business date. Existing data will be overridden.",
              businessDate);
      bpsMemoRepo.deleteByBusinessDate(businessDate);
    }
    if (bpsPriceRepo.countByBusinessDate(businessDate) > 0) {
      log.warn(
              "BPS Price record(s) found by {} business date. Existing data will be overridden.",
              businessDate);
      bpsPriceRepo.deleteByBusinessDate(businessDate);
    }
    if (bpsPositionRepo.countByBusinessDate(businessDate) > 0) {
      log.warn(
              "BPS Position record(s) found by {} business date. Existing data will be overridden.",
              businessDate);
      bpsPositionRepo.deleteByBusinessDate(businessDate);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not move `@Transactional` from `saveAllBpsPositionData` to `insertBpsPositionData`?  That way you don't need to think about propagation [which is not necessarily supported by your transaction manager](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-transactional-propagation-isolation)

Comment: The problem is most probably because you are calling an intercepted method locally. Unless you are using Spring's bytecode weaving for implementing the `@Transactional`, it will **not take effect for local calls**, e.g. for `this.overwriteBpsData(businessDate)`. Simplest solution is to move `overwriteBpsData` to another bean. REQUIRES_NEW should work (and I think it has more support than NESTED).

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos - So move overwriteBpsData into another component class, then use REQUIRES_NEW?

Comment: @Beez yes, that's the idea. The reason is that `@Transactional` is implemented in Spring (and JEE) with interceptors that work through the scoped proxy. If a call bypasses the scoped proxy, like local calls do, it also bypasses the functionality of `@Transactional`.